# Sum values for second level of multi-index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, multi-index

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with a multi-index of `'County ID'` and `'County'`. There is a `'Workforce'` column and I need to sum all the values in the column, then add that to another column in the `DataFrame`, but I need to sum only the values in each level. However ,I have been unable to get pandas to sum in this manner.

I've tried Many different things including making other `DataFrame`s to sum each index then re-add to the other `DataFrame`. I have also tried loops but have been unable to not sum all the values in the column together.

My dataframe looks like this: [image]

```
*COUNTY ID*   *COUNTY*             INDUSTRY  WORKFORCE  TOTAL WORKFORCE
12001      |  Alachua County, FL    Retail     25329        0
           |  Alachua County, FL    Health     22914        0
8013       |  Boulder County, CO    Education  24123        0
           |  Boulder County, CO    Finance    19478        0
# And so on in that manner
```

`'TOTAL WORKFORCE'` is a dummy column I added as an `int64` so that I could place a numerical value in it as a result of the sum I need.

I want to take all the workforce counts and add them together per each county so it would look like this:

```
*COUNTY ID*   *COUNTY*             INDUSTRY  WORKFORCE  TOTAL WORKFORCE
12001      |  Alachua County, FL    Retail     25329        48243
           |  Alachua County, FL    Health     22914        48243
8013       |  Boulder County, CO    Education  24123        43601
           |  Boulder County, CO    Finance    19478        43601
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `groupby` on `level=0` and transforming with the `sum` should do:

```
df['TOTALWORKFORCE'] = df.groupby(level=0).WORKFORCE.transform('sum')
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

An even shorter version:

```
df['TOTALWORKFORCE'] = df.sum(level=0).WORKFORCE
```

EDIT:
the assignment to

```
df['TOTALWORKFORCE']
```

will not work, as [Mark Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11747861/mark-wang) correctly mentioned. So this solution can only do the sum per country, without the assignment back to the original DataFrame.

Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I don't think column assignment would work given that the summed dataset has different index